# Tips on Using Epoxy Grout in Shower

Tags: shower, tile, grout, epoxy

I am working on a shower and would like to use epoxy grout on the floor.

I have been researching online about epoxy grout and tips to install it. I am looking for someone who has installed epoxy successfully and shares some tips. Apart from general tips like work on a small area, clean the tiles real good before grouting, etc.

I found the below tips as well:

I saw in a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wdWcLdmvqw) where they coated the tile with liquid soap before using epoxy grout. This helped clean up very easily. I am not sure if liquid soap would change epoxy chemistry and would this trick work with mosaic tile.

The second trick, I found was to use a bigger bucket with ice and place the epoxy grout bucket in it to reduce the temperature. This helps in increasing setting time. Has anyone tried that

The third trick, use a grout bag or empty caulking tube. Would this help?

Any tips or experiences are more than welcome. I m scared of using epoxy grout but want to use it for its superiority on a shower floor. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used epoxy grout a number of times and used different brands. The instructions have varied on cure times but the general procedure for application is the same. My advice would be to follow the instructions  supplied by the manufacturer accurately. I can't imagine coating tiles with liquid soap as the soap would get into the grout lines and be absorbed into the tile and prevent the grout from adhering to the tile. The ice bucket tip might slow down the curing time but that would be because it would stiffen up the grout and make application more difficult. Plus, the curing time is set by a chemical reaction, not so much by temperature. Using a caulk tube instead of a hard float is a bad idea because it won't force and work the grout into the grout lines like a float will do. Plus we all know how hard it is to get a smooth caulk line.

Bottom line, follow the instructions that come with your grout. You probably will have some extra tile or pick up a few pieces from your home store and practice a bit if you're unsure of your ability.

Comment: thank you for the advice. I can try to work with extra tiles and go from there. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for epoxy grout that I can use? I read that pre-mixed epoxy grout does not perform very well. 

And if I buy a three-part epoxy grout then could I prepare a small batch from the kit by mixing half of the ingredients? Or its advisable to mix the whole three-part kit to maintain consistency and chemical ratios?  Thanks

Comment: I have only used the two part epoxy and mixed the whole batch at one time. Mixing in smaller batches can be done but you will need the exact proportions or you risk the grout not hardening correctly. You also should use a mechanical mixer.

Comment: Thank you, so any two part grout at big bix store would be fine or you have any favorites?

Comment: @NIT_GUP  Anyone will be fine.  Pick one with longer setting time if possible so you have longer to work it.

Answer (score 0):

It is untrue that the soap would interfere with adhesion of the grout. Soap your tiles before using the epoxy. The tiles clean up with a sponge ,no haze. Once you tried it, you wouldn’t do it any other way. The cleanup is so easy using the soap. Also, stir the two part grout by hand (don’t use a mechanical mixer) until you get a consistent colour and texture. Too much mixing reduces working time. The soap acts as a release to prevent haze buildup. I’ve even heard of using commercial grout release on the tiles before applying the epoxy but I haven’t tried that.